# How to convert '2.6840000e+01' type like datas to float in Python?

Tags: python, types

I got a "input.txt" file that contains lines like:

> 1 66.3548 1011100110110010 25

Then i apply some functions column by column:

1. column stays the same,
2. column is rounding in a spesific way,
3. column is converted from binary to decimal,
4. column is converted from hexadecimal to binary.

And finaly i get this:

> [1.0000000e+00 6.6340000e+01 4.7538000e+04 1.0010100e+05]

Then i write this to "fall.txt".

All the operations is working correctly. But i want to see the numbers like:

> 1 66.34 47538 100101

I placed the columns of the relevant rows in `list_for_1`. Then i applied the functions to indexes and put them to another list `list_for_11`. Finally i put all the answers in a matrix. I wrote the matrix to the "fall.txt".

Here's what i did:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
#1. TİP SATIRLAR İÇİN GEREKLİ OBJELER
list_for_1 = list()
list_for_11 = list()
#list_final_1 = list()

for line in file:
    #EĞER SATIR TİPİ 1 İSE
    if line.startswith("1"):

        line = line[:-1]
        list_for_1 = line.split(" ")  #tüm elemanları 1 listede toplama
        #1. tip satır için elemanlara gerekli işlemlerin yapılması
        list_for_11.append(list_for_1[0])  #ilk satır 1 kalacak
        list_for_11.append(float_yuvarla(float(list_for_1[1])))  #float yuvarlama
        list_for_11.append(binary_decimal(list_for_1[2]))  #binary'den decimal'e
        list_for_11.append(hexa_binary(list_for_1[3]))  #hexa'dan binary'e
m = 0
n = 0
array1 = np.zeros((6,4))
for i in list_for_11:  #listedeki elemanları matrise yerleştirme
    if(m > 5):
        break
    
    if(isinstance(i, str)):
        x = int(i, 2)
    array1[m][n] = float(i)
    n += 1
    if(n == 4):
        n = 0
        m += 1

with open("fall.txt","w") as ff:
    ff.write(str(array1))
    ff.write("\n")
```

Over here i actually send float type to matrix but it's not working:

```
        if(isinstance(i, str)):
            x = int(i, 2)
        array1[m][n] = float(i)
```

I'm sort of a new python user, so i might write unnecessarily long and complex codes. If there's any shorter way to do what i did, i would like to get opinions for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to format your numbers the way you want them:

```
def formatNumber(num):
  if num % 1 == 0:
    return int(num)
  else:
    return num
```

Your list of numbers:

```
l = [1.0000000e+00, 6.6340000e+01, 4.7538000e+04, 1.0010100e+05]
```

Reformatting your list of numbers:

```
for x in l:
    print(formatNumber(x))
```

Output:

```
1
66.34
47538
100101
```

Comment: It worked for lists, so thanks for that. But i want to convert all the elements in a matrix. I tried `for row in range(0,6):
        for column in range(0,4):
            array1[row][column] = formatNumber(array1[row][column])` and when i tried to print types, it still printed types as `numpy.float64`